# query linking max(col) and associated col in row to different table

Tags: mysql, sql, max, inner-join

I have 2 tables:

```
**Inbox**
- InboxID
- PostID
- UserID
- datePosted

**Users**
- UserID
- FName
- SName
- Pic
```

And What I need to do is get the highest datePosted val in the Inbox table where the userID is not equal to a particular val passed in and the postID IS equal to a val I pass in. Then I need to get the FName, SName and Pic of the UserID which is in the same row as the highest datePosted val.

My attempt:

```
SELECT
    MAX(Inbox.datePosted),
    uSERS.uSERid,
    Users.FName as commenterFname, 
    Users.SName as commenterSName,
    Users.Pic as commenterPic
FROM
    Inbox
    INNER JOIN Users
        ON Inbox.UserID = Users.UserID
        WHERE PostID = 807 AND Inbox.userID <> 36
```

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: @Strawberry 1. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/80b83/1 2. result desired: 1441971872, 411, Jimmy, Page, url/imageCache144163378768235363JPEG_20150907_145107_-1640092258.jpg

Comment: Please edit your question accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested... Select rows where datePosted is equal to max datePosted.

```
   SELECT
        Inbox.datePosted as datePosted,
        uSERS.uSERid     as uSERid,
        Users.FName      as commenterFname, 
        Users.SName      as commenterSName,
        Users.Pic        as commenterPic
    FROM Inbox
      INNER JOIN Users ON Inbox.UserID = Users.UserID
    WHERE PostID = 807 AND Inbox.userID <> 36
      and datePosted = (select max(datePosted)
                        FROM Inbox
                          INNER JOIN Users ON Inbox.UserID = Users.UserID
                        WHERE PostID = 807 AND Inbox.userID <> 36)
```

Comment: Oops, didn't know. I'll re-write. Back soon.

Comment: @jarlh my structure has changed since this question, but I have a new question here if you have the time: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32583553/query-linking-4-tables